# How to set up a priority for a query in MemSql

Tags: singlestore

Is there a way to set priorities for queries in Memsql?  I know that for MySql there are High/ Low priority Options . Are they applicable for MemSql too?

Answer (score 1):

There is no query priority setting in MemSQL currently. If you need to prioritize queries, you will have to do it client-side.